# Suggestion of activities calendar in LaTeX

Tags: captions, double-sided

Is there any way to make a kind of activities calendar to put five activities per month in LaTeX, what would you recommend to make it look nice.

Something like:

```
Month      Activities    
---------------------
January   1.
          2.
          3.
February  1.
          2.
          3.
....
```

I was thinking in

```
\begin{center}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|c|p{3.5in}|}
        \hline
        Month      & Activities \\ \hline
        January   &  1.  \\\newline &2.  \\\newline &3 \\ \hline
        February & 1.  \\\newline &2.  \\\newline &3 \\ \hline
       March       & 1.  \\\newline &2.  \\\newline &3 \\ \hline
        ~        & ~          \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{center}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this, also I am not getting that centered.

Comment: For the centering problem: use `\begin{table}\centering` instead of `\begin{center}\begin{table}` (see [Should I use center or centering for figures?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2651/2552))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use the `booktabs` package, which gives you nice horizontal lines and appropriate vertical spacing, lose the vertical lines (they don't make the table clearer but introduce clutter), use one table row per activity, and use slightly larger vertical spacing to separate the months (you can do this with `\\ \addlinespace`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}\centering
\caption{Calendar of Activities}

\begin{tabular}{ll}\toprule
Month & Activities  \\\midrule
January & 1. Eat    \\
    & 2. Drink  \\
    & 3. Sleep  \\\addlinespace
February & 1. Read  \\
    & 2. Think  \\
    & 3. Write  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]